# Bash- Run multiple commands at the same time

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to run multiple commands at the same time, but not moving on until both are finished? I have been trying to use similar instructions to the following, but both take a long time to complete and would be better if I could run them at the same time (cannot use `&` to run it on the background since the next step requires all the output files)

```
sed -i 's/x/y/' file1
grep 'pattern' file2 > file3
```

Comment: `( command )`. this launches a subshell. it's multi-processing. then you can call `wait` on both pid. have a look at a complete doc: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html.

Comment: You can use & and wait

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you want:

```
sed -i 's/x/y/' file1 &
grep 'pattern' file2 > file3 &
wait
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer, but a few lines of makefile would do what you want

```
file1:
    sed -i 's/x/y' <someinput

file3: file2
    grep 'pattern' file2 > file3

nextop: file1 file3
    whatever you want to do next
```

and make -j so that tasks are done in parallel when possible